# What adding type_t to array means in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have no experience with C++ but there is an algorithm that I am translating to Dart. There is one part that is adding a size_t to an array and there is another part that is subtracting a pointer from an array. What does it do? I don't even know how to search on Google, your help will be very appreciated.

What does Array + size_t does? https://gist.github.com/lslv1243/0a7dc586997d9f449722cab13ebd7c5e#file-map-cpp-L771

What does a pointer to an element that is in the array - the Array does? https://gist.github.com/lslv1243/0a7dc586997d9f449722cab13ebd7c5e#file-map-cpp-L803

I provided links to the full code because I don't know how to create a simpler example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you at least show the pieces of code that you are confused by? This stuff should be covered in any introductory text though.

Comment: I don't know how to create a simpler example. But the code is at this line https://gist.github.com/lslv1243/0a7dc586997d9f449722cab13ebd7c5e#file-map-cpp-L771 (the addition) and this line https://gist.github.com/lslv1243/0a7dc586997d9f449722cab13ebd7c5e#file-map-cpp-L803 (the subtraction)